# Is a varchar unlimited in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Is a varchar unlimited in Postgresql? I read this text online and it was confusing:

"In PostgreSQL, the Varchar data type is used to keep the character of infinite length. And it can hold a string with a maximum length of 65,535 bytes."

Does that mean that in postgres, a varchar can only hold a maximum of 65,535 characters? Or can a varchar hold an unlimited amount of characters?

I need to be able to hold an unlimited amount of characters in the database table. There is a lot of incoming data that could get into the millions of characters per column.

Edit:

So based on replies, is looks like the 65,535 character limit is not true. What is the limit then? Someone said 1GB. Is that true? Is there a way to make a varchar truly unlimited?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

Comment: "*And it can hold a string with a maximum length of 65,535 bytes.*" - is plain wrong. You shouldn't trust random sites on the internet. If in doubt, the manual is your friend.

Comment: "*Someone said 1GB*" - yes, the manual does.

Comment: "Is there a way to make a varchar truly unlimited?" no, everything has as storage limit and in postgres it's 1GB for regular values (values stored in columns). The only way to bypass that is to use LOBs (Large Objects), which have a completely different interface but support streamed retrieval, allow partial updates, and can store up to 4TB.

Comment: There is no `CLOB` type. Masklinn was referring to [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html) which are used in a completely different (and much more complicated) way. If you really need to store strings greater than 1GB I strongly recommend a different storage solution, not a relational database.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The limit for `varchar` when you specify a length limit (type modifier) is 10485760:

```
SELECT 'x'::varchar(1000000000);
ERROR:  length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760
```

Without the type modifier, the size can be up to 1GB (just like `text`).

Answer (score 5):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)

> if character varying is used without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size.

"Of any size" means up to 1GB as that is the maximum length of any column value.

> In any case, the longest possible character string that can be stored is about 1 GB